# How to convert string To DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My two classes are shown here:

```
public class GigFormViewModel
{
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public byte Genre { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time)); }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Gig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` instead.

Comment: Why don't you show us the string?

Comment: Can you please show an example input for `Date` and `Time` properties?

Answer (score 4):

Use `ParseExact`, suppose you have the string `string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time)` in format `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt` like `01/11/2016 12:00 PM` then you can do it by

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time), 
          "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: great, happy coding